# Zend framework 2 skeleton application issue

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, http-status-code-404

I have start working on the zend framework 2 and I need help on issue i have facing. I have followed the skeleton tutorial and but when i try go album page it gives me 404 error. Can any one help on this?

I have mention few thing i have change on the apache config file and virtual host file. The home pages is working(http://Myalbum).

But when try to locate "Album" page it was display 404 error.

**Apache config file**

```
Directory "F:\xampp\apps\myapp\htdocs"
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Require all granted
/Directory

DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs"
```

**virtual host file**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

VirtualHost *:80
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
/VirtualHost

VirtualHost *:80
     ServerName Myalbum
     DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/apps/myapp/htdocs/public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     Directory "F:/xampp/apps/myapp/htdocs/public"
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     /Directory
/VirtualHost
```

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ49c.jpg)

Comment: Did you configure your router correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use something like myalbum.localhost (lowercase + localhost subdomain) rather than Myalbum.

You have to add the hostname in your host file :

```
127.0.0.1 myalbum.localhost
```

Then restart Apache.